# How to search for a XML node and add or delete it using xmlstarlet

Tags: xml, shell, scripting, xmlstarlet

I try to create a shell script that searches in an XML file for an attribute and create an element with the given attribute if this doesn't exist or delete the element if the attribute exists.

Here is the XML File:

```
<configuration name="distributor.conf" description="Distributor Configuration">
  <lists>       
    <list name="CRproductionLoadshare">
      <node name="fs100" weight="2"/>
      <node name="fs101" weight="2"/>     
    </list>
    <list name="AnyOtherGroup">
      <node name="fs100" weight="2"/>          
    </list>
  </lists>
</configuration>
```

And this is my Shellscript so far:

```
fs_name=fs
cnt=102
xmlstarlet ed \
  --var fs "'$fs_name$cnt'" \
  -a '//list' -t elem -n node -v "$fs_name$cnt" \
  -i '//node' -t attr -n name -v "$fs_name$cnt" \
  -i '//node' -t attr -n weight -v 2 \
  -d '//node[.=$fs]/text()' <distributor.conf.xml
```

The expected Output is

```
<configuration name="distributor.conf" description="Distributor Configuration">
  <lists>       
    <list name="CRproductionLoadshare">
      <node name="fs100" weight="2"/>
      <node name="fs101" weight="2"/>  
      <node name="fs102" weight="2"/>    
    </list>
    <list name="AnyOtherGroup">
      <node name="fs100" weight="2"/>          
    </list>
  </lists>
</configuration>
```

But my script work like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration name="distributor.conf" description="Distributor Configuration">
  <lists>
    <list name="CRproductionLoadshare">
      <node name="fs100" weight="2" name="fs102" weight="2"/>
      <node name="fs101" weight="2" name="fs102" weight="2"/>
    </list>
    <list name="AnyOtherGroup">
      <node name="fs100" weight="2" name="fs102" weight="2"/>          
    </list>
    <node name="fs102" weight="2"/>
  </lists>
</configuration>
```

How to change the shell script to reach the goal. At first, I want to add the node name="fs102" in case of that this node didn't exist.

Comment: your input/output does not cover the 2nd part of your condition **or delete it if it exist**. Elaborate your conditions

Comment: Right, I want to create the add condition at first, if this works I will create the second, maybe in a separate script.

Comment: How do you decide where to put the node. As I see, you can place it in `<list name="CRproductionLoadshare">` as well as `<list name="AnyOtherGroup">`. Why do you only want to create the node in the first potential parent and not in the second.

Comment: I want to add the node element in the list element with name CRproductionLoadshare, as in my answer I only add the element in the CRproductionLoadshare named list element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most difficult task at hand here is to build the XPath that selects the correct node.

### Step 1: find the XPath you need

**example 1:** Select the node named `list` who has an attribute `@name="CRproductionLoadshare"` and has a child named `node` with attribute `@name="fs100"`.

So you can search for the parent of that particular node named `node`.

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t                                                            \
        -m '//node[@name="fs100"]/parent::list[@name="CRproductionLoadshare"]' \
        -c . -n foo.xml
```

```xml
<list name="CRproductionLoadshare">
      <node name="fs100" weight="2"/>
      <node name="fs101" weight="2"/>     
</list>
```

or a bit easier :

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t                                                        \ 
       -m '//list[@name="CRproductionLoadshare" and node[@name="fs100"]]'  \
       -c . -n foo.xml
```

**example 2:** Select the node named `list` who has an attribute `@name="CRproductionLoadshare"` and **does not** have a child named `node` with attribute `@name="fs102"`.

Here we can use the XPath `not`-function

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t                                                        \ 
       -m '//list[@name="CRproductionLoadshare" and not(node[@name="fs102"])]'  \
       -c . -n foo.xml
```

```xml
<list name="CRproductionLoadshare">
      <node name="fs100" weight="2"/>
      <node name="fs101" weight="2"/>     
</list>
```

### Step 2: edit your XML-file with the XPath you just found

#### A: Just add the node if it is not there

So, since you now know the correct XPath to select the node, you can edit the XML-file accordingly by first inserting a subnode `-s` and then updating its values and attributes with `-i`

```
$ xpath1='//list[@name="CRproductionLoadshare" and not(node[@name="fs102"])]'
$ xpath2='//list[@name="CRproductionLoadshare" and not(node[@name="fs102" and @weight="2"])]/node[last()]'
$ xmlstarlet ed -s ${xpath1} -t elem -n "node"   -v ""      \
                -i ${xpath2} -t attr -n "name"   -v "fs102" \
                -i ${xpath2} -t attr -n "weight" -v "2"     \
                foo.xml
```

which outputs

```xml
<configuration name="distributor.conf" description="Distributor Configuration">
  <lists>
    <list name="CRproductionLoadshare">
      <node name="fs100" weight="2"/>
      <node name="fs101" weight="2"/>
      <node name="fs102" weight="2"/>
    </list>
    <list name="AnyOtherGroup">
      <node name="fs100" weight="2"/>
    </list>
  </lists>
</configuration>
```

#### B: Toggle the node

Toggling can be done by adding a fake attribute and then remove the node with that attribute:

```
$ xpath0='//list[@name="CRproductionLoadshare"]/node[@name="fs102"]'
$ xpath1='//list[@name="CRproductionLoadshare" and not(node[@name="fs102" and @delete="1"])]'
$ xpath2='//list[@name="CRproductionLoadshare" and not(node[@name="fs102" and @delete="1"])]/node[last()]'
$ xpath3='//list[@name="CRproductionLoadshare"]/node[@name="fs102" and @delete="1"]'
$ xmlstarlet ed -i ${xpath0} -t attr -n "delete" -v "1"     \
                -s ${xpath1} -t elem -n "node"   -v ""      \
                -i ${xpath2} -t attr -n "name"   -v "fs102" \
                -i ${xpath2} -t attr -n "weight" -v "2"     \
                -d ${xpath3}                                \
                foo.xml
```

Comment: Thanks, this script add the node but do not delete the element in case that still exist. I want to toggle the element add in case that didn't exist or delete in the case that exist. In my answer the script can toggle but in your answer there are more detailed information about how it work. If you also add the delete function I will add your answer as the right one.

Comment: @kockiren, so do I understand correctly that you want to: a) if the node is there, replace it with a new one and b) if the node is not there, add it. Or is it, a) if the node is there, delete it and b) if the node is not there, add it.

Comment: If the element node with attribute name="fs102" exist it should be deleted and if the element doesn't exist it should be create.

Answer (score 2):

> search in a XML file for a attribute and create it if this doesn't
>   exist

```
fs_name="fs"
cnt=102

node_exists=$(xmlstarlet sel -t --var fs="'${fs_name}$cnt'" -v 'boolean(//list[@name="CRproductionLoadshare"]/node[@name=$fs])' distributor.conf.xml)
[ "$node_exists" = "false" ] && xmlstarlet ed -O -s '//list[@name="CRproductionLoadshare"]' \
-t elem -n node -i '//list[@name="CRproductionLoadshare"]/node[last()]' \
-t attr -n name -v "${fs_name}$cnt" \
-i '//list[@name="CRproductionLoadshare"]/node[last()]' -t attr -n weight -v 2 distributor.conf.xml
```

The output:

```
<configuration name="distributor.conf" description="Distributor Configuration">
  <lists>
    <list name="CRproductionLoadshare">
      <node name="fs100" weight="2"/>
      <node name="fs101" weight="2"/>
      <node name="fs102" weight="2"/>
    </list>
    <list name="AnyOtherGroup">
      <node name="fs100" weight="2"/>
    </list>
  </lists>
</configuration>
```

---

Scheme:

- `node_exists` is assigned with boolean value indicating the needed node existence
- `[ "$node_exists" = "false" ] && xmlstarlet ed ...` - the 2nd `xmlstarlet` *edit* command will be only executed if the `node_exists` is not equal to `false`

Comment: Thx, the node[last()] for addressing the last inserted node looks interesting, what I have found was with a temp variable, is this the same like your syntax?

Comment: One more issue is to reference only the node in list CRproductionLoadshare, if there is a different list with different name than the new node will add in every list element. But maybe this is a different question? I have updated the question if you think it is for a new topic please delete my edit.

Comment: If I use your script and the node name fs102 exist in the CRproductionLoadshare list element you're script add one more node fs102 element

Comment: Okay that works for adding the node if the node doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

The shell script that works for toggle the node looks like this:

```
fs_name=fs
cnt=102
inputfile=distributor.conf.xml

if [ -n "$(xmlstarlet sel -T -t -v "//list[@name='CRproductionLoadshare']/node[@name='$fs_name$cnt']/@name" $inputfile)" ]; then
  echo "$fs_name$cnt already defined in $inputfile"
  xmlstarlet ed -L -d "//list[@name='CRproductionLoadshare']/node[@name='$fs_name$cnt']" $inputfile
else
  echo "adding $fs_name$cnt to $inputfile"
  xmlstarlet ed -L -s  "//list[@name='CRproductionLoadshare']" -t elem -n TempNode -v "" \
    -i //TempNode -t attr -n "name" -v "$fs_name$cnt" \
    -i //TempNode -t attr -n "weight" -v "2" \
    -r //TempNode -v node \
    $inputfile
fi
```

Each time I run that script the inputfile toggle the node (add/delete) only in the list element with name CRproductionLoadshare.