# Sed insert string on new line post string Linux

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have been trying to use sed for the following -
I am searching in a file for the below keyword -

```
</Remote>
```

And right after it, on new line, am trying to insert following -

```
<ScanConfig filesToTest="ABCD_*.csv" namePatternLogic="0" scanMethod="0" subdirsScanLevel="" />
```

I have tried standard SED -

```
sed -i '</Remote>/a <ScanConfig filesToTest="ABCD_*.csv" namePatternLogic="0" scanMethod="0" subdirsScanLevel="" />' somefile.txt
```

OR

```
sed -i '\#^ *</Remote> *$# a\ <ScanConfig filesToTest="ABCD_*.csv" namePatternLogic="0" scanMethod="0" subdirsScanLevel="" />' somefile.txt
```

Both failed with below errors -

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `<'
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `"'
```

I suspect the special characters in the line I am trying to insert which has <, /> characters is confusing SED.
I tried to use escape characters with /\ though it didn't quiet work out.

Can someone please help me with this?
Thanks.

Comment: It is always good to post expected output in CODE TAGS too.

Comment: First of all welcome to Stack Overflow. We understand that you are excited about parsing XML with regex, [but just do not do it!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/8344060) Tools such as sed and AWK are extremely powerful for handling text files, but when it boils down to parsing complex-structured data — such as XML, HTML, JSON, ... — they are nothing more than a sledgehammer. Yes, you can get the job done, but sometimes at a tremendous cost. For handling such delicate files, you need a bit more finesse by using a more targetted set of tools.

Comment: Have a look at the following two answers that give you some insight how you could attack this problem using [tag:xmlstarlet]. ([answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51441662/8344060) and [answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50716547/8344060)). Note, these answers are not the solution to your problem but show a methodology.

Answer (score 1):

This one should work

```
sed  -i '/<\/Remote>/a <ScanConfig filesToTest="ABCD_*.csv" namePatternLogic="0" scanMethod="0" subdirsScanLevel="" />' file.txt
```

In your first script you forgot to add "/" in the beggining of sed expression.

Also you have to use "\/" to match "/" if you're using it as sed delimiter.

Comment: so don't use `/` as the sed delimiter, use some other char, e.g. `:</Remote>:a ...`

Comment: You have to add "\" if you're using other delimiter than `/`  `sed '\:</Remote>:a ...'`

Comment: I feel like that's better than having to escape characters within the regexp you're trying to match.

Comment: Thanks Guys, solution suggested by JUSHJUSH worked perfectly! Thanks once again.